# Как с помощью python requests грамотно отправить post запрос с типом 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests

С помощью Wireshark поймал post запрос, сразу обратил внимание, что какой-то он странный:

(ловил у десктопного приложения)

```
POST /api/log/post?sessionId=%7BF0А3A03B-6D8F-4E3A-8DF1-DDC114098F%7D&created=2021-08-05T09:09:37&category=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5&note=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F.%20%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF:%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD&fileType= HTTP/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0
Host: log.test.ast.test.ru
Accept: text/html
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
```

Нагуглил что такое "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" и даже что то типо примеров, но что т фигя какая то получилась.

```
url = 'http://log.test.ast.test.ru/api2/log/post'
#мне даже не оч понятно откуда брать урл
data = {
    'sessionId': '{F0D409FE8F}',
    'created': '2021-08-05T09:09:38',
    'category': 'Информация о системе',
    'note': 'Получение информации о системе',
    'fileType': 'HTTP/1.0'
}


header = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': '0',
    'Host': 'log.test.ast.test.ru',
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'
}

r = requests.post(url=url, headers=header, data=data)
```

Кидаю это, ловлю свой пакет wareshark'ом, а там в всё в одну строку без заголовка, в общем не похоже на тот пакет что выше.
Как правильно его отправить, что бы он был похож на исходный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр `data=` нужен для отправки тела запроса, а в вашем примере тела нет (видно по заголовку запроса `Content-Length: 0`)

А то, что передается в параметрах запроса (`?sessionId=%7BF0А3A03B-6D8F-4...`) выполняется через `params=`

Поменяйте так:

```
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=header, params=data)
```

Comment: Спасибо!________________________________

Comment: @СергейПопков, пожалуйста :)